# How can I make the same comment color?

Tags: html, json, tags

Like here

[image: 1]

How can I make the same comment color?
I tried to change themes, values in settings.json "editor.tokenColorCustomizations", but it always changed not only the color of the text or tag, but all together.But I would like it to be like in the screenshot

Comment: Not enough information. What editor is this? [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you can change the color of the text of the comment with this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "comment",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C69650", // Your custom color
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Probably the color of the tag will change with a theme or another "scope" item.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fulfill my desires.

The code below makes the comment the way I wanted it to be

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#e9cf44",
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": "comment",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#5eff00a8", // Your custom color 5eff00
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkoC5.png)